# How to monitor registry accessing? [C#]

Tags: c#

I have a C# Service running as LocalSystem (lets call it Serv.exe), and I need this service to monitor all registry accessing.

Specifically whenever a call to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software*.* is made by any of the processes it launches I need to catch that call (either a change or simply accessing) so that I can redirect it accordingly - I know of the CHANGE events but what about just accessing the registry to get a value?

The reasoning (incase someone has a better suggestions - which I would more then welcome) - the Service is running under LocalSystem which has its own HKEY_CURRENT_USER but this service is used to install software in the background of a logged-on user - so when this software is installed  it may try to affect the HKEY_CURRENT_USER of the USER itself (which is fine) - so I need to ensure that these changes are reflected to the USER and not the LocalSystem account.

Any advice, help, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Do not forget to accept answer once a solution is good for you. I see that you have 9 questions without any accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) if you just want to see what is going on.

Redirection is complex; you'll need to hook APIs with a library like [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), but the license to use it in production is expen$ive.  That said, Process Monitor is still useful to ensure that your API hooks are doing the right thing.

Do the processes launched by your service need to continue to run as LocalSystem?  If not, try [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the process created under the appropriate account.

If your needs are simpler, such as getting a carelessly written app to run without write access to HKLM, the [Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=24DA89E9-B581-47B0-B45E-492DD6DA2971&displaylang=en) may be the ticket.

Unfortunately, installation is the nastiest case of all.  You may need to resort to the clumsy hack of having your service add the user to the Administrators group, launch the installer with CreateProcessAsUser, then remove the user from the Administrators group again once the process is launched, similar to Aaron Margosis's [MakeMeAdmin script](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaron_margosis/archive/2004/07/24/193721.aspx).

If the installer is that bad, you may have better luck collecting the necessary HKCU registry settings (use Process Monitor, or `reg export` HKCU before and after installation and diff them) into a `.reg` file, and cobble up some sort of startup script that imports the registry entries on login (and leaves a breadcrumb so it doesn't re-run for the same user and overwrite their settings).  I've used this approach for specialty applications that insist on keeping everything in HKCU.

If you don't mind digging down into undocumented depths, your service running as LocalSystem can do [some complicated hocus-pocus involving essentially undocumented APIs like `ZwCreateToken`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/RunUser.aspx) to run the installer in the user's session with the local Administrators group added.  This also has some limitations -- for example, a token created without a password will not have network credentials.

Comment: SysInternals Process Monitor doesn't have an API (that I know of) - so not sure how it can help my service. As for the other 2 - I'll do some reading and see - never heard of them before (thanks).

Comment: Problem is - I can't impersonate - I do not have the Username or Password for any of the accounts after the service is installed ... that is my major reason for doing the installation as a LocalSystem Service.

Comment: I thought you could impersonate with a passed token (not creating it yourself with LogonUser) if a process in the user's session hands it to you.

Comment: But if I use imporsonation - don;t I loose my security also? To be able to install as Administator (LocalSystem)?

Comment: So the issue is you're trying to work around a broken installer that needs to run once in each user account with admin rights?

Comment: Pretty much ... that and an installer that reflects everything to HKEY_CURRENT_USER but is expected to work under all user accounts (stuck with what I got).

Comment: I feel your pain... vertical apps and novel USB device support apps tend to be the worst offenders.  With internal apps you can usually LART the developers :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393964%28VS.85%29.aspx) queries.  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WMI_RegistryMonitor.aspx) is an example.

Comment: But doesn't that only work for CHANGES to the registry? I need to handle accessing it also.